# usage of multiprocessing.shared_memory

Tags: python, multithreading, module, process, shared-memory

How do I use multiprocessing.shared_memory to share information between processes. I found limited information on internet (as I understand it was added recently to Python)

Regards

Edit:
I have program that does something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func():
     tup = # do something to generate tuple
     sharedmemory = tup # place tuple in shared memory

sharedmemory = (0, 0, 0) # place tuple with values zero in sharedmemory
p = Process(target=func) 
p.start()
p.join()

print(sharedmemory) # here I expect to get the tuple I generated in function (child process)
```

Those do not necessarily need to be tuples, can also be lists as conversion to list is pretty easy lol

What is the best and easiest way to achieve this shared memory? I know that I probably oversimplify it but if you know how to do it can you please explain it well or provide some good documentation (code example would be best).
Regards

Comment: In a border sense, you it is specific to loop parallelism ?

Comment: please post a sample code that you're trying to use multiprocessing in and the context of your work which you want to use shared_memory with.

Comment: You can use higher-level data types such as dictionaries, arrays, etc. that are backed by shared memory and not deal directly with shared memory. See `multiprocessing.Manager()` which returns an instance of `multiprocessing.SyncManager` and its methods (e.g. `dict`) and also look at such methods as `multiprocessing.Array`, `multiprocessing.Value`, etc.

Comment: I've read that multiprocessing.shared_memory should be faster than Value and Array, idk